# Extension method in a portable class library is not visible in Asp.net MVC views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's my problem:

We have made a portable class library that contains a class CommonColors, that contains a list of colors that all our client softwares can use as a common color scheme of the product. Before the colors were defined in a non-portable class library where they worked fine, but now they cannot be accessed in the web client views. Everywhere else (Asp.Net code-behind, WPF) they work fine.

Clients include a Asp.Net web client with razor views, a WPF client and there will be a mobile client of some sort.

The error we get during runtime is: "CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToHtmlColorValue' and no extension method 'ToHtmlColorValue' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Assembly references are correct, there is a reference in the web project to the portable class library. They are referred like so in the views:

```
@{
string bgcolor = "#" + MySpace.Common.CommonColors.MyTestColor.ToHtmlColorValue();
}
<div id="testdiv" style="background-color:@(bgcolor);">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

Here's the color class in my portable class library project:

```
namespace MySpace.Common
{
    public static class CommonColors
    {
        private static string FromRgb(int r, int g, int b)
        {
            return r.ToString() + "," + g.ToString() + "," + b.ToString();
        }

        public static string ToHtmlColorValue(this string rgb)
        {
            string result = "000000";
            try
            {
                string[] parts = rgb.Split(',');
                int r = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                int g = int.Parse(parts[1]);
                int b = int.Parse(parts[2]);
                result = r.ToString("x2") + g.ToString("x2") + b.ToString("x2");
            }
            catch
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string MyTestColor = FromRgb(100, 165, 0);

        // more colors...
    }
}
```

I'd like to understand what exactly is causing this problem and fix the implementation into more elegant and good code. Currently we can just add a line @using MySpace.Common to every view that uses the colors but that makes unreliable code that requires coder to know/remember to use that using statement or else get unexpected errors during runtime.

Adding the using statement makes the method visible in the views but referring it in the view using the same namespace path does not. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your static variable MyTestColor and make you FromRgb public like this:

```
namespace MySpace.Common
{
    public static class CommonColors
    {
        public static string FromRgb(int r, int g, int b) 
        {
            return r.ToString() + "," + g.ToString() + "," + b.ToString();
        }

        public static string ToHtmlColorValue(this string rgb)
        {
            string result = "000000";
            try
            {
                string[] parts = rgb.Split(',');
                int r = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                int g = int.Parse(parts[1]);
                int b = int.Parse(parts[2]);
                result = r.ToString("x2") + g.ToString("x2") + b.ToString("x2");
            }
            catch
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it this way:

```
@{
    var rgb = CommonColors.FromRgb(1, 1, 1);
    string bgcolor = "#" + rgb.ToHtmlColorValue();
}
```

For additional, you can add your namespace in your web.config to make it visible all throughout your views without adding the namespace like this.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MySpace.Common" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks Jr, that's correct ToHtmlColorValue is an extension method for the strings in the class. I tried adding the prefix as in your example but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: The error is the same as before: CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToHtmlColorValue' and no extension method 'ToHtmlColorValue' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to either add the using like @JrTabuloc did above, or in your view do `@using MySpace.Common;`

Comment: No Johan, I prefer not to use those in the views as they bring a possibility for errors. I'd prefer to refer to the colors using the path MySpace.Common.CommonColors.MyTestColor in the views. However the web.config edit above seems to fix the problem, for some reason the extension method is not visible in the views without adding the namespace either to web.config or to each view individually. Thanks both for your help!